# Не получается нарисовать два графика на одной координатной оси в matplotlib или tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, matplotlib, графики

Первый график y = √(-x^2 + x + 1) и второй график y = tg(x). Как их нарисовать?
Должен получиться такой график: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Было бы неплохо указывать, что именно не получается. Потому что на самом деле, все замечательно получается:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import math

xi = np.arange(-25, 25, .001)
yi1 = [math.sqrt(x - x**2 + 1) if (x - x**2 + 1)>=0 else float('nan') for x in xi]
yi2 = np.tan(xi)

plt.figure(figsize=(10,4))
plt.ylim([-10, 10])
plt.grid()
plt.plot(xi, yi2)
plt.plot(xi, yi1)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]